# Why won't pagination work?

Tags: posts, pagination, templates, pages, blog

I am using a page template with code to display all blog posts:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Blog */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="main">

<?php
// ACF Page number variable
$numposts = get_field('number_of_posts_per_page');
$args = array( 'numberposts' => $numposts );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?>

    <div class="blogpost clearfix">
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <span class="postdetails">
    <?php the_time ('j F, Y'); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="bullet">&bull;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Posted by:&nbsp;<?php the_author(', '); ?>&nbsp;in:&nbsp;<?php the_category(', '); ?><?php the_tags( '&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="bullet">&bull;</span>&nbsp;&nbspTags: ', ', ', '<br />' ); ?>
    </span>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>


<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The problem I'm having is I cannot get any pagination to work. Above I have pagenavi installed but nothing appears. I have set the post limit to 5 in both my custom field (which shows 5, there are 6 posts) and in WP settings.

Can anyone shed any light? Thanks.

Comment: I believe it was my loop that sucked, this is fixed, thanks.

Comment: Post your solution for anyone who comes after you to use.

Answer (score 2):

probably coz you override the default query and forgot to take care of pagination :-)
change the code this way:

```
$page = isset(get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => $numposts, 'paged' =>  $paged );
```

This should do the work

Answer (score 0):

I have to say it's unusual to see someone using a custom template for a blog considering the `index.php` is for this; I guess it depends on your set up. I'd suggest being careful whenever doing custom queries.